# Alert object not working in emulator using cordova project+zend project+json+ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cordova, zend-framework

I am developing a Cordova application connected to an external database that ajax+json handling sending and received request from a PHP document developed with Zend.

My issue is when I am inserting a client a message alert content an JSON text pop but the problem is the alert box show in navigator but not shown in emulator. In emulator the message shown in a new page in JSON form.

Here is example from the code

```js
function AjaxForm(idform){
   
   $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
      
        beforeSend : function() {$.mobile.loading('show')},
     complete   : function() {$.mobile.loading('hide')},
     url: $("#"+idform).attr('action'),
     data: $("#"+idform).serialize(),
     success: function(response){
       var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
       if(obj.status=="success"){
      //navigator.notification.alert(obj.message);
       alert(JSON.stringify(obj.message, null, 4));
     
     }else{
       
      //navigator.notificationalert(obj.message);
        alert(JSON.stringify(obj.message, null, 4));
      
     }
      },
   error      : function(response) {
    //console.error("error");
       var obj = JSON.parse(response);
    alert(JSON.stringify(obj.message, null, 4));            
   }
   });
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="http://197.28.10.36/mbankingfinal/public/atbservice/clients/save" id="idformulaire">

   <input type="text" name="login_client" id="login_client" placeholder="Login"/>

   <input type="text" name="password_client" id="password_client" placeholder="Mot de passe"/>
<center>
<div class="ui-input-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b">
   <input type="submit" value="Valider" id="sublogin" data-theme="b" >
</div>
<div class="ui-input-btn ui-btn-b ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b">
 <input type="reset" value="Reset"  data-theme="b">
 </div>
 </center>
   </div>
  </form>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#authentifier", function( event ) {
  
 
   $(document).on('click', '#sublogin',function(e) {
   if(e.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
   {
     AjaxForm('idformulaire');
    e.handled = true;
     e.preventDefault();
   }
  }); 
  
});
</script>
My PHP ZEND code 
public function saveAction(){
    
     $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
     //$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    
  $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
  
     if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
      $values = $this->_request->getPost();
      $id =   $this->_getParam('id');
    
      unset($values['submit']);
      try{
       $tableClients = new Application_Model_Clients_DbTable() ;
       if(!empty($id)){
        $where = array("login_client = ?" => $id);
        $tableClients->update($values, $where);
       }else{
        $tableClients->insert($values);
       }
       echo '{"status":"success","message":"Insertion effectué avec succée"}';
       
      }catch (Zend_Db_Exception $e) {
       echo '{"status":"error","message":"'.$e->getMessage().'"}';
       
      }
    
     }
    }
```

in navigator, shows an alert that content " Insertion effectué avec succée "
but in emulator it load another page content:

```
{"status":"success","message":"Insertion effectué avec succée"}
```

in both of case the data insert in database but the display is the problem.